# How to evaluate a symbolic expression in different ways?

Tags: python, list, sum, sympy, evaluation

I have a list of symbolic expressions, like below:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy
s = sympy.Symbol('s')
x = [ s, s+1, 10*s**2, 5]
```

After adding the elements by using "sum":

```
y = sum (x)
```

I will get: `10*s**2 + 2*s + 6`
I want to evaluate this expression for each of the elements of the list below:

```
s = [1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
```

I know that I can define a function like below:

```
def F (s):

    F = 10*s**2 + 2*s + 6
    return F
f_dis = [F(value )for value in s]
```

and it will give the result I'm looking for: `[18, 50, 102, 174, 266]`
However, my problem is that I have to define the F and write the expression in my code. Is there any other way that I can evaluate the `sum (x)` without writing the `F = 10*s**2 + 2*s + 6` inside my code? 
I can not copy and paste the result of `sum (x)` inside my code.

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html. `ans = [y.subs(s,el) for el in alist]` You should not rename `s` as that list. Give it another name and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution is using [`fun.evalf`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html#subs-evalf) to evaluate your function. You can create the function by adding all the terms using `Add`, SymPy's [Advanced Expression Manipulation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#)

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, Add

s = Symbol('s')
x = [s, s+1, 10*s**2, 5]
s_values = [1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
fun = Add(*x) # Create a function by adding all terms. * is to unpack all the values

def F(fun, v):
    return fun.evalf(subs={s: v}) # Evaluate the function at s=v

f_dis = [F(fun, v) for v in s_values]   

# [18.0000000000000,
#  50.0000000000000,
#  102.000000000000,
#  174.000000000000,
#  266.000000000000]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy
s = sympy.Symbol('s')
x = [ s, s+1, 10*s**2, 5]

a = [1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]

evals = [sum(x).subs(s, el) for el in a]
```

Output

```
[18, 50, 102, 174, 266]
```

Complex number

```py
a = [1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5, 1+1j]

evals = [sum(x).subs(s, el).as_real_imag() for el in a]
```

You can easily parse the tuples to get the first element.

```py
def re_(tpl: tuple) -> float:
    return tpl[0]

def img_(tpl: tuple) -> float:
    return tpl[-1]
```

Or

```py
a = [1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5, 1+1j]

evals = [sum(x).subs(s, el).evalf() for el in a]
```

Output

```py
[18.0000000000000, 50.0000000000000,
102.000000000000, 174.000000000000,
266.000000000000, 8.0 + 22.0*I]
```

But the last one will have to be converted to complex.

Comment: Thanks, it works too. but the only problem is that if I change one element of list s to be complex, the code does not return a simplified value for my complex number. For example, insert 1+1j instead of 1 in the list, and you will get 8.0 + 2.0*I + 10*(1.0 + 1.0*I)**2 instead of 8.0 + 22.0*I. the eval function handle this issue but it's slow.

Comment: Hi @AmirRezaJalali. Maybe my new edits to the answer will help

Answer (score 1):

Or compute the sum once and use it in a lambda:

```
>>> x = [ s, s+1, 10*s**2, 5]
>>> sumx = sum(x)
>>> do = lambda si: sumx.subs(s, si)
>>> list(map(do, range(1, 6)))
[18, 50, 102, 174, 266]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works too. but the only problem is that if I change one element of list s to be complex, the code does not return a simplified value for my complex number. For example, insert 1+1j instead of 1 in the list, and you will get 8.0 + 2.0*I + 10*(1.0 + 1.0*I)**2 instead of 8.0 + 22.0*I. the eval function handle this issue but it's slow.

Comment: You can change `do = lambda si: sumx.subs(s, si).expand()` and then it will work for that case, too.